# How to use the result of a function call as condition of the loop and in the body of the loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following concept works in the C and C++ languages, you assign the result of a function to a variable and then use the newly assigned variable as the condition for the while loop.  So using the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#:%7E:text=function%20called%0A7.000000-,Built%2Din%20comma%20operator,The%20comma%20operator%20expressions%20have%20the%20form,-E1%20%2C%20E2).

A sample bit of C++ code looks like this. I've mocked the behavior of a function call by doing an assignment from an array. In my real situation the function only provides the value once and I want to use it as the condition but also in the while body loop. There isn't another end condition available to me.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int vals[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    int var = 0;
    int i=0;
    while(var = vals[i], var != 3){ // vals mocks the function
        std::cout << var << std::endl; // mock usage of value stored in var
        i++;
    }
}
```

What would be a pythonic way to take the results of my function call, use it as a conditional in my loop and use it in my loop body? In other languages the do-while loop could solve this problem but python doesn't have it.

Comment: @Vlad, super! Also nice that the name of the operator is a better (searchable) one than just 'comma'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One line if-condition-assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872838/one-line-if-condition-assignment) or [Assign within if statement Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30066516/assign-within-if-statement-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The so-called "walrus operator" (introduced in 3.8) is ideal for this.

Here's an example:

```
def func():
    return 1 # obviously not a constant

while (n := func()) != 0:
    print(n) # infinite loop in this example but you get the point
```